# Probability of Correctly Guessing Coin Toss when Changing the Guess

Tags: probability

Generally when tossing a coin $n$ times, the probability of getting heads or tails are both $\frac{1}{2}$ for each toss, so if you were to guess heads for every toss, you should expect to get $\frac{1}{2}$ of the tosses correct.

Now I also understand that for $n$ tosses to consecutively be all heads, the probability would be $(\frac{1}{2})^n$.

**With this in mind, if you were trying to maximize the amount of correct guesses for $n$ coin tosses, should you be changing your guess after each successful prediction?**

It would seem to me that after you successfully guess the toss, let's say for example your guess was heads, the probability of it being heads *again* on the next toss is now $(\frac{1}{2})^2$, right? So intuitively it would seem like changing your guess to tails in this case would yield a higher success rate for the next toss and so on.

Does this logic stand? I'm trying to figure out a way to prove mathematically that this would work (or doesn't work) and I'm coming up short. Any help in trying to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To avoid a biased coin you simply throw on another "rng", like a clock or if you are currently breathing in or out. Apart from that, if you have a fair coin you can safely "guess" all heads and have the same EV as if you guess randomly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: @saturatedexpo so it's best to treat each toss as independent?

Comment: yes, in that case. There are cases where the tosses are not independant. Such as bad implementation of the rng. (like building a machine that replicates tosses, which has been done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is incorrect. The probability of the second toss does not depend on the outcome of the first toss, therefore it is not a conditional probability problem. So whether you were right or wrong on the first toss the probability of the second toss is ($\frac{1}{2}$). If you were to guess the next two tosses then the probability of getting them both right would be $(\frac{1}{2})^2$ no matter what your guess was for each toss, same goes for the nth case.

Comment: I see, so when trying to guess each individual toss the probability will always be 1/2 and it's only (1/2)^n when I'm trying to guess n tosses at once?

Comment: yes, that would be like tipping the endscores of 10 footballmatches in a row. (to give you a feel about it)